# Modify an existing item based on ID

Tags: web-part, development, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise

The following code is what is I use to insert new list items:

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite  = SPContext.Current.Site)
 ' using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
 ' 
 SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["SampleList"];

 SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
 itemToAdd["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
 itemToAdd.Update();
```

How do I do "itemToAdd["Title"] = TextBox1.Text", by modifying an existing item where ID=4 rather than add a new item?

Comment: What do you mean "where ID = 4"? If the item has not been added to the list, it does not have an ID yet.

Comment: Assuming there are 10 items in the list with column x and y, I would like to add "SampleText" under field y if field x is "test" for that particular item.

Comment: That's not what you put in the question - do you want to update an item based on it's ID or based on the value of another field?

Comment: @MikeRedden I apologize if the question was not very clear. But what spdevsolutions has posted below is exactly what I was looking for.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to edit Mike's more, but here's a cleaner answer instead (sorry Mike!):

Basically there is no reason to make a new spsite object, also you should never really call .items (like ever, it will go get the entire list), and you don't need to call dispose on a spsite.Rootweb...

Anywhere here you go:

```
SPWeb oSPWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["SampleList"];
SPListItem ItemToModify = list.GetItemById(4);
ItemToModify["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
ItemToModify.Update();
```

As a side comment, since I don't have enough rep over here to comment on the question post: It isn't a good idea to do list.items.add() (MSOCAF may actually even error on this, don't remember), as calling .items will pull the entire list. Do this instead: http://sharepointdevsolutions.blogspot.com/2010/02/adding-items-to-large-lists.html

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. It was exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

To modify the title of an item in your list with an ID of 4, do the following:

```
using (oSPSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.URL))
{
     SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPSite.RootWeb;
     SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["SampleList"];
     SPListItem ItemToModify = list.Items.GetItemById(4);
     ItemToModify["Title"] = TextBox1.Text;
     ItemToModify.Update();

}
```

And another thing: NEVER put a site out of SPContext into a "using" statement - that will dispose of the current context and will cause a lot of heartache in the future. If you insist on having your own SPSite object instead of just utilising the context, create a new SPSite object like I have above.